# Are performance engineering questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Would questions about performance engineering motors on topic here? For instance, questions like "What would be the best pistons to run in a supercharged Honda b16a motor?" (not sure if that's the best example, but just something to give an idea.)

Comment: Any questions with "best" in them generally set off the "subjective & argumentative" red flags.  Aside from that, I give this a +1 because I believe there *are* questions on this subject which could be on-topic for this site.

Comment: Ah yeah, I can see how that would be a subjective example. I was just trying to think of a question that would exemplify "performance engineering." I'm trying to think of some good questions to throw up on the new site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By its very nature, car performance dives off into the subjective weeds pretty quick.

However, I agree that performance questions would be okay, as long as "best" is kept out of the equation.

- I am working on a Honda b16a with XYZ supercharger.
- My compression ratio is X:Y.
- I have this and that and whatjamagic and doohickies all installed.
- Whenever I increase the boost to 20psi, I get knocking.
- Do I need to get 110 octane fuel or is there a way to reduce the knocking with some hardware? Do I need to reprogram the ECU to ROM 1.2?

Granted, this type of question could still end up with argumentative responses, because everyone has their favorite whatjamagics and doohickies, but at least it doesn't *invite* arguments as much as a "best" question.